# Loading JSON into Google Area Chart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to load json data into a Google Chart, as they do [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example). To simplify things to begin with I'm defining the json in the html file. I can get the example to work fine (it's a pie chart), but when I try to do it with an area chart it doesn't work. Here is what I'm doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = 
              {
                cols: [{id: 'A', label: 'NEW A', type: 'string'},
                       {id: 'B', label: 'B-label', type: 'number'},
                       {id: 'C', label: 'C-label', type: 'date'}
                ],
                rows: [{c:[{v: 'a'},
                           {v: 1.0, f: 'One'},
                           {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28, 0, 31, 26), f: '2/28/08 12:31 AM'}
                      ]},
                       {c:[{v: 'b'},
                           {v: 2.0, f: 'Two'},
                           {v: new Date(2008, 2, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '3/30/08 12:31 AM'}
                      ]},
                       {c:[{v: 'c'},
                           {v: 3.0, f: 'Three'},
                           {v: new Date(2008, 3, 30, 0, 31, 26), f: '4/30/08 12:31 AM'}
                      ]}
                ]
              };

        var data = google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
</script>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width:900; height:500"></div>
```

It doesn't plot anything with the above code. I'm sure the problem is really trivial and stupid, but can anyone tell me what it is?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: First error is Uncaught Error: You called google.visualization.DataTable() without the "new" keyword

Comment: After that I believe your data is wrong. An area chart I think needs numbers as both x and y (you have numbers and dates). I plugged into a sample and changed to numbers and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/L1tct3Lv/25/

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot Kevin, your solutions worked. I didn't realize area charts couldn't be on dates, guess I'll have to switch to line charts instead.

Comment: I posted as an answer to finish out this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error is Uncaught Error: You called google.visualization.DataTable() without the "new" keyword. After that, examine the data. I do not believe you can combine dates and numerics into an area chart, it expects numbers.

I plugged into a sample and changed to numbers and it works: jsfiddle.net/L1tct3Lv/25

```
    var jsonData = 
          {
            cols: [{id: 'a', label: 'NEW A', type: 'string'},
                   {id: 'b', label: 'B-label', type: 'number'},
                   {id: 'c', label: 'C-label', type: 'number'}
            ],
            rows: [{c:[{v: 'a'},
                       {v: 1.0, f: 'One'},
                       {v: 100}
                  ]},
                   {c:[{v: 'b'},
                       {v: 2.0, f: 'Two'},
                       {v: 200}
                  ]},
                   {c:[{v: 'c'},
                       {v: 3.0, f: 'Three'},
                       {v: 300}
                  ]}
            ]
          };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```